# Spark Structured Streaming dynamic lookup with Redis

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, streaming, lookup

i am new to  spark.
We are  currently building a pipeline :

1. Read the events from Kafka topic
2. Enrich this data with the help of Redis-Lookup
3. Write events to the new Kafka topic

So,  my problem is  when i want to  use spark-redis library it performs very well, but data stays static in my streaming job.

Although data is refreshed at Redis, it does not reflect to my dataframe.
Spark reads  data at first then never updates it.
Also  i am reading from REDIS data at first,total data about 1mio  key-val string.

What kind of approaches/methods i can do, i want to use Redis as in-memory dynamic lookup.
And  lookup  table  is changing almost 1 hour.

Thanks.

*used libraries:*
spark-redis-2.4.1.jar
commons-pool2-2.0.jar
jedis-3.2.0.jar

**Here is  the code part:**

```
import com.intertech.hortonworks.spark.registry.functions._
val config = Map[String, Object]("schema.registry.url" -> "http://aa.bbb.ccc.yyy:xxxx/api/v1")
implicit val srConfig:SchemaRegistryConfig = SchemaRegistryConfig(config)
var rawEventSchema = sparkSchema("my_raw_json_events") 


val my_raw_events_df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "aa.bbb.ccc.yyy:9092")
.option("subscribe", "my-raw-event")
.option("failOnDataLoss","false")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",1000)
.load()
.select(from_json($"value".cast("string"),rawEventSchema, Map.empty[String, String])
        .alias("C"))


import com.redislabs.provider.redis._
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val stringRdd = sc.fromRedisKV("PARAMETERS:*") 
val lookup_map = stringRdd.collect().toMap
val lookup = udf((key: String) => lookup_map.getOrElse(key,"") )



val curated_df = my_raw_events_df 
.select(

     ...
     $"C.SystemEntryDate".alias("RecordCreateDate")
    ,$"C.Profile".alias("ProfileCode")     
    ,**lookup(expr("'PARAMETERS:PROFILE||'||NVL(C.Profile,'')")).alias("ProfileName")**
    ,$"C.IdentityType"     
    ,lookup(expr("'PARAMETERS:IdentityType||'||NVL(C.IdentityType,'')")).alias("IdentityTypeName")     
     ...

).as("C")



import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

val query = curated_df
   .select(to_sr(struct($"*"), "curated_event_sch").alias("value"))
   .writeStream
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "aa.bbb.ccc.yyy:9092")
   .option("topic", "curated-event")
   .option("checkpointLocation","/user/spark/checkPointLocation/xyz")
   .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("30 seconds"))
   .start()

   query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: did you consider just using Redis Streams instead of Kafka?

Comment: Hi Korland,
Raw events coming  to KAfka  as json and  have to enrich them while streaming.

Comment: Could you please share some details which approach are you following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to not use spark-redis, but rather lookup in Redis directly. This can be achieved with `df.mapPartitions` function. You can find some examples for Spark DStreams here https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/07/lookup-additional-data-in-spark-streaming/. The idea for Structural Streaming is similar. Be careful to handle the Redis connection properly.

Comment: Will try and share the results

Comment: Special thanks,  i tried  mappartitions and it only creates  connnection for per partition.But i have another problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240504/spark-streaming-reach-dataframe-columns-and-add-new-column-looking-up-to-redis  
special thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to do a stream-static join ([spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-static-joins)):

Instead of collecting the redis rdd to the driver, use the redis dataframe ([spark-redis docs](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/doc/dataframe.md#reading)) as a static dataframe to be joined with your stream, so it will be like:

```
val redisStaticDf = spark.read. ...
val streamingDf = spark.readStream. ...

streamingDf.join(redisStaticDf, ...)
```

Since spark micro-batch execution engine evaluates the query-execution on each trigger, the redis dataframe will fetch the data on each trigger, providing you an up-to-date data (if you will cache the dataframe it won't)

Comment: Hi @talgo10, that sounds interesting. will try this one. But the main concern for Redis data is  key-value. i mean some people put data to redis as key-val. So i have to think about how manage this part also.