# Spark Streaming reach dataframe columns and add new column looking up to Redis

Tags: apache-spark, redis, streaming, lookup

In my previous  question([Spark Structured Streaming dynamic lookup with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64592973/spark-structured-streaming-dynamic-lookup-with-redis) ) , i succeeded  to reach  redis with mapparttions thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/689676/fe2s

I tried to use   mappartitions  but  i could not solve one point, how  i can reach  per row column in the below code part while  iterating.
Because  i want to enrich my per-row against my lookup fields kept in Redis.
I found something  like this, but how i can reach dataframe columns and add new column looking up  to Redis.
for any help  i really much  appreciate,  Thanks.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def transformRow(row: Row): Row =  {
    Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[Any]("val1", "val2"))
}

def transformRows(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] =
{ 
    val redisConn =new RedisClient("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",6379,1,Option("Secret123"))    
    println(redisConn.get("ModelValidityPeriodName").getOrElse("")) 
    //want to  reach  DataFrame column here   
    redisConn.close()
    iter.map(transformRow)     
}

val newSchema = StructType(raw_customer_df.schema.fields ++ 
    Array(
            StructField("ModelValidityPeriod", StringType, false), 
            StructField("ModelValidityPeriod2", StringType, false)
        )
  )

spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(raw_customer_df.rdd.mapPartitions(transformRows), newSchema).show
```

Comment: why don't you use the spark-redis connector? (https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/)

Comment: Hi Korland,  ok  we can but that is  not the issue. The main concern  how i can access  dataframe rows and columns while doing lookup with Redis  in  mappartitions.
Any  help  greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterator `iter` represents an iterator over the dataframe rows. So if I got your question correctly, you can access column values by iterative over `iter` and calling

```scala
row.getAs[Column_Type](column_name)
```

Something like this

```scala
def transformRows(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[Row] = {
    val redisConn = new RedisClient("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",6379,1,Option("Secret123"))
    println(redisConn.get("ModelValidityPeriodName").getOrElse(""))
    //want to  reach  DataFrame column here
    val res = iter.map { row =>
      val columnValue = row.getAs[String]("column_name")
      // lookup in redis
      val valueFromRedis = redisConn.get(...)
      Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array[Any](valueFromRedis))
    }.toList

    redisConn.close()
    res.iterator
  }
```

Comment: Hi fe2s,  
Thanks  for  suggestion.
what can be done for  schema  of this dynamic  added fields?

Comment: Also ,  in orginal dataframe there  nested  columns. 
val columnValue = row.getAs[String]("C.field1") 
this  gave error  while reaching  to the nested columns

Comment: Hi @mustangc. Didn't understand the question regrading schema. As for accessing nested columns, it should be possible with something like this row.getAs[Row]("C").getAs[String]("field1")

Comment: Hi, @fe2s.
I fixed  the issue of nested  items parsing  like this: 
        var BirthPlaceCityCode =  Try( row.getAs[Row]("ObjectLevel1")
                             .getAs[GenericRowWithSchema]("ObjectLevel2")
                             .getAs[Integer]("BirthPlaceCityCode")).getOrElse(-1).toString 

this is  OK.


my main purpose is:   
a)  ReadStream from  kafka topic
b)  Enrich withRedis and "add new columns"
c)  WriteStream to kafkatopic "with new columns"

so, while doing WriteStream  should i use  foreachbatch  ?

Special thanks